# Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/python3

Tags: raspbian, linux, sudo

I've created a startup script in bash that calls a Python script.  However when I run "sudo sh StartUpScript.sh" from the command prompt it says:

> "Sorry, user root is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/python3
>   /home/pi/python Indoor-Air-Quality-MQTT.py' as root on user1.

I'm logged on as a user called remoteuser and I've given remoteuser full privilege in sudoers.

> remoteuser      ALL=(ALL:ALL) AL

Any ideas how ti can get this script to run?

Comment: To be honest this is more of a [U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) question...

Answer (score 1):

The path shown does not look correct:

`/home/pi/python Indoor-Air-Quality-MQTT.py`

Looks like it should be:

`/home/pi/python/Indoor-Air-Quality-MQTT.py`

(notice the `/` between python and Indoor)

From the now-deleted answer:

`ls -l "/home/pi/python Indoor-Air-Quality-MQTT.py"`

1. Verify the permissions of the python script.
2. Verify the python script is executable.

`ls -ld "home/pi/python"`

3. Verify the permissions of the directory containing the script.

The post also suggested adding an entry to `/etc/sudoers` to remove the need to run as root.